# Java negative lookahead to exclude words

Tags: java, regex

I'm writing a regex in Java to match names, but want to exclude matches for lines that contain certain words: "Deputy Clerk" or "Electronic Recording" (case-insensitive).

This is my regex:

```
(?i)(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)+(?-i)([A-Z][A-Za-z. '-]{5,}(?i)(?:,? +[JS]R +\.)?)(?!Deputy Clerk|Electronic Recording)
```

I intend for it to match only the first of the following 3 lines, but it's returning matches for all 3 at the moment.

```
Hon. Judge: Amy D. Hogue
HONORABLE    Lesley Briones Jr.     JUDGE          DEPUTY CLERK
HONORABLE      JUDGE PRO TEM       ELECTRONIC RECORDING MONITOR
```

What's wrong with my negative lookahead? https://regexr.com/4o3sr

Comment: Which words are blacklisted (i.e. what is the list of forbidden words) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen "Deputy Clerk" and "Electronic Recording". I've edited my post.

Comment: Please add the language behind the regex you're trying to make.

Comment: See https://regex101.com/r/7JedgH/1 The words you try to fail against are captured into Group 1. You either need to fail all if there is any of the banned words to the right of the left-hand context, or temper Group 1 pattern.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, your regex was exactly what I needed. Can you explain - maybe in an answer - what you mean by "temper the Group 1 pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words you try to fail against are captured into Group 1, its pattern grabs the text that contains these words and since there are not clear-cut boundaries nor group pattern tempering the lookahead returns true since it does not find the banned phrases at the string location of the current index.

You may use

```
(?i)(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)++(?!.*(?:Deputy Clerk|Electronic Recording))((?-i:[A-Z])[A-Za-z. '-]{5,}(?:,? +[JS]R +\.)?)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7JedgH/3)

To only fail if the banned prases are whole words, add word boundaries:

```
(?i)(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)++(?!.*\b(?:Deputy Clerk|Electronic Recording)\b)((?-i:[A-Z])[A-Za-z. '-]{5,}(?:,? +[JS]R +\.)?)
```

Note you may get rid of the second `(?i)` if you use a modifier group: `(?-i:[A-Z])`.

Once `(?!.*\b(?:Deputy Clerk|Electronic Recording)\b)` is placed after `(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)++`, it will fail the match if anywhere to the right there is one of the alternative in the non-capturing group.

Also, I suggest using a possessive quantifier after `(?:(?:Hon(?:orable)?|Judge)[:. ]+)` to match and fail invalid strings quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I would keep it simple and just use:

```
^(?i)(?!.*\b(deputy clerk|electronic recording)\b).*$
```

### Demo

This pattern asserts that the phrases `deputy clerk` and `electronic recording` do not occur anywhere in the line.